# Fargate instance - what is utilizing disk space?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, storage, aws-fargate

I have a fargate instance i'm running and need disk space (ephemeral storage) for some data processing.
I'm running a modified ubuntu image which sits at about 700MBs
I'm running the new fargate platfrom 1.4.0 that provides a minimum of 20GB of space.

I'm running out of space when i believe the space I have should be sufficient.
I put some logging code in my python app to tell me how much space is on disk

```
INFO:__main__:Total: 24 GiB

INFO:__main__:Used: 5 GiB

INFO:__main__:Free: 17 GiB
```

My question is, why is there 5GiB used inside of the container instance? When I run the container locally and jump into it via an interactive shell, I do not see 5GiB of space being used.

I can't find anything in the aws documentation or docker documentation to indicate what this might be.

I've also run the container multiple times and those numbers are consistent.

Want to know if there is a simple answer I'm missing before I start trying to debug this further.

Comment: How are you doing that disk space calculation?

Comment: am on python 3.6 and using shutil.
`total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("/")

print("Total: %d GiB" % (total // (2**30)))`